# .gitignore with C# visual studio

Tags: c#, git, gitignore

I've just started this C# project `Reversi`, copied some C# .gitignore template into my folder. I've just done my first commit:

[image]

To my eyes it is saving wayy too many files with git, but I'm not sure what is and what is not neccesary. What should I add to the `.gitignore` to reduce the clutter but not throw away anything usefull?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the files it looks like you are using Visual Studio.
Try this gitignore:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably add `.vs/` to `.gitignore`. The rest looks fine to me.